# Mobile Library or examples for image gallery

Tags: android, jquery, ios, css, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create an image gallery for mobile devices which is somewhat like this :

https://developer.apple.com/safaridemos/showcase/gallery/

(horizontal 3D option specifically).

Is there a library to create such a gallery for mobile devices(touch enabled scrolling instead of next and prev buttons)?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.photoswipe.com/

Comment: @MelanciaUK you can post that as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/ is a nice one using ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a jQuery plugin for the jQuery Mobile UI:

[PhotoSwipe](http://www.photoswipe.com/)

Posting as an answer instead of a comment, as per your request.

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Though it is helpful, but it still isn't exactly what I needed. The link that I'd shared has another style of gallery display.

Answer (score 3):

Mobile image gallery loaded via `$.ajax` and uses swipe for navigation

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/05/27/awesome-mobile-image-gallery-web-app/

Comment: Though it is helpful, but it still isn't exactly what I needed. The link that I'd shared has another style of gallery display.

Comment: @KazekageGaara The example you've provided is wonderful, however, i think if looks better on tablets rather on mobile devices. Images will look tiny. Nevertheless i assume its do-able on mobile devices since it uses CSS `-webkit-transform` and `-webkit-transition`.

Comment: I know it's do-able, but I was searching for a library, instead of implementing the whole stuff on my own. Would reduce the testing time.

Comment: I'm willing to assist, I like such heavy jobs ;) @KazekageGaara

Answer (score 0):

I used this for the purpose:

http://www.mobify.com/mobifyjs/modules/carousel/

Easier to use, and renders well.